# Cruise control - project list is so long on dashboard - can we have folders?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

CC.Net is pretty cool and we have been using it in our organisation for just under a year now.
However the project list is on about 30 projects at the moment. and It takes ages just to scan though the list looking for the correct build and trying not to click on the wrong one!

Is there anyway to group builds into folders on the dashboard UI i.e. this screen:

[image]
(Random CCNEt dashboard image I found on the web)

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashboard doesn't support project grouping in subfolders. However, the project-configuration `<project>` tag includes a `queue` option - by grouping projects into queues, you not only gain a way of subdividing your project list for display purposes, but also get the extra features that allow control over duplicate build requests and mutual-exclusion between project builds (if you want them).

Our CC.NET server is building around 100 or so projects - the dashboard looks very confusing by default, but by making use of queues you get a list of them in the left pane, which filters the project list to just show those in the selected queue. That filter adjusts the URL too, so you can hyperlink directly to a filtered view if you need to.

[CruiseControl.NET Queue Documentation](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Queue%20Configuration.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `<category>` element in your project definitions. Your projects will be grouped by the different category values in the dashboard. For details see the [documentation](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Project%20Configuration%20Block.html).

For example:

```
<project name="Project 1" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
  <category>Category 1</category>
```